# Axios get response headers. Works in node, not in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, header, axios

I will start off by saying this has nothing to do with authentication of JWT tokens.

I am trying to pull data from a public api. Lets call it www.abc.com/WeatherAPI.

When I do this in node with axios using `axios.get(url)`, I am able to `console.log(res.headers)` and they show perfectly.( I need them for pagination and a recursive function)

When I use the EXACT SAME code in react, I get empty headers returned.... 
eg: `content-type: "application/json"
date: "Sun, 08 Mar 2020 09:23:03 GMT"`

Code:

```
    return axios
      .get(
        'https://api.xxxxxxxx' +
          (cursor ? '&cursor=' + cursor : '')
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.headers['cursor']);
        // If there is no data, return...
        if (res.data.length < 1) return;

        // Push current data into OB state
        setOB({ ...oB, ...res.data });
        //te

        //If there is no cursor... ie there is no more data, return
        if (!res.headers['cursor']) return;


        return OB(res.headers['cursor']);
      });
  };

  // I dont know if use effect is right here... we will see..
  useEffect(() => {
    OB();
  }, []);`
```

Comment: Post full code here

Comment: Too big to post here so: https://pastebin.com/bXDLnXSu

Comment: Do you see your request to the api in the browsers **network** tab?

Comment: Yes, and I can see the cursor there too... hmm

Comment: have you solute that??
I'm on the same issue.. @Syyymilds

Answer (score 0):

as the API is public, it could be that the response header differs based on the agent. it is not likely to be the case but it can be. I would suggest overriding the headers object including the `User-Agent`

```
axios.get(
   `https://api.xxxxxxxx${cursor ? '&cursor=' + cursor : ''}`,
    { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'YOUR-SERVICE-NAME' }  },
).then()...
```

Comment: This had no effect unfortunately